# Wine application in Gnome requires an extra click to become focused

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

I'm using Tera Term, a Windows virtual terminal emulator with Wine due to a legacy application. Everything else works wonderfully, but for some reason the window requires two clicks to gain focus. After being minimized it at first comes to the foreground and only becomes focused when its "tab" is pressed again on the lower panel.

On Linux I cannot use some keys such as F1-F12 without specifying another terminal manually during login, this extra hassle is not justifiable for the end-user. With TeraTerm it seems to work out of the box.

I did not actually install the software in the usuaul sense - I just ran the executable that I copied from a Windows installation and it worked just fine besides the focus issue. I'm not actually using Ubuntu, but a modified version of it called Estobuntu which comes with some additional Estoninan software.

I have come up with a temporary solution, but it is still a bit inconvenient by setting the gnome windows to gain focus on mouse over movement.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain why you need tera-term - there are better linux based terminal emulators such as Putty - what doesnt work when you use a linux based terminal emulator?

Comment: On Linux I cannot use some keys such as F1-F12 without specifying another terminal  manually during login, this extra hassle is not justifiable for the end-user. With TeraTerm it seems to work out of the box.

Comment: Please add that comment into your question - further question - what version of ubuntu are you using and what version of wine are you using?  Was it a simple "setup.exe" install or did you have to do anything extra?

Comment: Questions should relate to an accepted version of Ubuntu on this site (http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).  Please try an official version to confirm whether this is still an issue.

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu for this purpose any more, that "solved" it.

Answer (score 2):

This could between wine and compiz. Wine doesn't get along with compiz very well. You could switch from compiz to metacity. I don't know what exactly you are doing but you could use another terminal program like mincom. Here the source for the problem:

http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-db2fa150a8b8f906508959b92beb00768ec6ec47

Could also be another problem with the wine configuration for the app but since I don't know your config and there are many things which could get wrong I don't know if this is your problem.

Comment: I'd prefer it if I didn't have to give up using Compiz nor TeraTerm. Compiz provides me with the ability to apply rules (making windows unresizable and unmaximizable) to Windows, this is required because it doing the former messes up the terminal-based app.

Comment: No, it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Too bad. You could try another version of TeraTerm or download the source code and try to compile it for the use on linux. Or play around with the wine settings.